# Unable to fully install Elementary OS Luna on iMac 11.1

Tags: boot, elementary-os, amd-graphics, proprietary-drivers

I have tried to install Elementary OS  Luna 64-bit on my iMac 11.1 (late 2009, Intel Core i5 processor, ATI Radeon HD 4850 graphics card).
At this moment it's working but not very well. I will give you a summery of my installation process and my problems.

First off I made a bootable USB using VMware and Startup Disk Creator. Other methods did not work.
When I boot up the EOS USB get a grub screen, I need to hover over Install EOS then press the `e` key to edit the code.
I type `nomodeset xforcevesa` and press F10 to boot. Now I am able to install EOS, I select my partition and make it ext4.

At the end of the installation it asks me to reboot, I press on reboot and the first time I get just a black screen, so I reboot again and get the Grub screen with EOS and EOS recovery mode options. I need to hover the mouse cursor over EOS again and press the `e` key to edit. I again type `nomodeset xforcevesa` and press F10 to boot. It does not boot up in GUI mode but in console mode (terminal).
It asks me for my username and my password, which I gave. Then type `startx` and get the error `no screens found`.

I looked around and found on the ubuntuforums.org that it had something to do with having hybrid graphics.
I used the info on [this site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics) and ran the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty # raring and saucy did not work
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-trusty # raring and saucy did not work
sudo apt-get install fglrx-experimental-13
sudo apt-get install fglrx-pxpress
sudo reboot
```

Now it boots up in GUI mode, but I have an invisible mouse for the first 2 minutes.
When the mouse cursor becomes visible it's not a normal cursor but a X pointer. I open some apps and discover that the apps have no window borders. I look around again and find it has probably something to do with fglrx. I open the terminal and run `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`  and reboot the system.

The first time I reboot I get a black screen, so I reboot again and get the Grub screen again with the choice between EOS and EOS recovery.
I need to hover the mouse over EOS again and press the `e` key to edit. I type `nomodeset xforcevesa` and press F10 to boot.

Now it boots with a normal mouse cursor and I have window borders. I install Firefox and the Flash plug-in and discover that video is not working good, on YouTube it doesn't have 30 frames/sec, more like 10 frames/sec which make makes watching videos impossible. I look on the web again and find at Ubuntu Forums that I need to install the right graphics driver.

I go the AMD site to download Catalyst legacy 13.1 (the last version that supports my graphics card).
I run the download in the terminal, the program pops up, I tried to install it, but it gave me the error `more tools required`.
My second attempt was using ppa:makson96/fglrx. It did not work. It crashed EOS, so I needed to repeat the process all over again.

*Summary*

1. EOS boots up only once every two times, and when it does I need to manually force the boot parameters `nomodeset xforcevesa`.
2. I'm not able to watch any videos because of the slow response.